# How to pass a value from one Jasmine JavaScript test to another test

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I am testing reading and writing (to a server, to a mongo db).
I know, I am not supposed to do this, I should be using mocks, ... but anyhow
I want to write a document, read that document to make sure it is was correctly written,
then delete that document, then verify it is gone.  So I have 2 problems that I have solved but by using 2 hacks.

1) how do I pass along the mongo **_id** of the document from step to step.  I'd like to have a simple variable in my Jasmine code that I can read and write from each test. I am hacking it now by creating a variable in the actual Angular module that I am testing, and reading and writing a variable over in that code.

2) since I have to wait for each IO operation before proceeding, I am taking advantage of the
 `setTimeout(() => {done();}, 2000);`  feature in a set of nested  `beforeEach(function(done){`
sections.

I would like to learn simple, better ways of doing these if there are any.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is called integration tests.  Nothing wrong with doing them, but I usually write integration tests using Angular's E2E facilities.

That said, just save the value in a global variable and it will change each test.  Some psuedo code

```
describe('integration test', () => {
 let id;
 it('should create a document', () => {
   // code to create item and return id
   id = _id;
 }
 it('should load document', () => {
    console.log(id);  // should be value from create test
 }
 it('should delete document, () => {
    console.log(id);  // should have value from create test
 }
}
```

Since the id value is never set in a `beforeEach()` it will retain its value between tests in the same `describe()` block.

I have cautions about this when writing unit tests--because the tests must run in a specific order to execute.  But, the desire is that E2E / integration tests are run sequentially.

Comment: Great, you answered the first part.  I kept sticking this. in front of (what in your code is) id.  as in this.id   thanks much.